# Strange SharedPreference in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have already worked in SharedPreference before and I have never experienced such a strange error ever. I am implementing SharedPreference like normal human beings do. But while I try to retrieve the data that is stored in it, it gives me a **CLASSCASTEXCEPTION** !!! The code is as follows :

**CODE :**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    row_item_object = array_list_object.get(position);
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);


    adapter_object = new AddToListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.add_to_list_repeat_items, array_list_object);

    editor = sp.edit();

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);;

    if(convertView == null)
    {

    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.add_to_list_repeat_items,null);
    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_to_wants_owns_textview);
    holder.count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_to_wants_owns_count);
    holder.frame = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.frame);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();




    holder.title.setText(row_item_object.getTitle());

    System.out.println("Sample is " + row_item_object.getTitle());

    System.out.println("The count value in position 0 is " + sp.getInt("count_key_wants",0));


    /*if(position == 0)
    {

        int shared_prefs_count_value_wants = sp.getInt("count_key_wants", 0);
        row_item_object.setcount(shared_prefs_count_value_wants);
    }

    if(position == 1)
    {
        int shared_prefs_count_value_wants = sp.getInt("count_key_owns", 0);
        row_item_object.setcount(shared_prefs_count_value_wants);
    }*/


    holder.frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddToListRowItem sel_row = null;
            int pos = position;
            System.out.println("Position on frame click: " + pos);

            System.out.println("The title is " + row_item_object.getTitle());

            if( pos == 0 )
            {
                sel_row = array_list_object.get(pos);
                System.out.println("Inside AddToWants");


                    sel_row.setTitle("Added To Wants");




                    count_value_wants = count_value_wants + 1;
                    sel_row.setcount(count_value_wants);

                    editor.putInt("count_key_wants", count_value_wants);

                    editor.commit();



                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();





            }
            else 
            {
                //AddToListRowItem sel_row = array_list_object.get(pos);
                System.out.println("Inside AddToWants");
                sel_row = array_list_object.get(pos);
                sel_row.setTitle("Added To Owns");


                    count_value_owns = count_value_owns + 1;

                    sel_row.setcount(count_value_owns);

                    editor.putInt("count_key_owns", count_value_owns);
                    editor.commit();


                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();



            }

        }

    });


    return convertView;
}
```

I believe the code looks like something done by a human. The error originates at the SOP line stating as a ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.
What could possibly be going wrong ?????

Why am I getting this error ? Even if the Shared Preference object is not instantiated properly, it should throw me a NullPointerException or it should print the default value which I have given as 0. Neither happens.

**NOTE :** I have been implementing this in a **non-activity** class that extends ArrayAdapter.

**Logcat :**

```
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:221)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at com.example.addtolistfeb_21.AddToListAdapter.getView(AddToListAdapter.java:93)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2006)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1245)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1420)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1138)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
02-22 20:31:46.873: E/AndroidRuntime(18240):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The 93rd line in logcat is the SOP line. Any insights on what might be causing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you initially declaring `count_value_wants`?

Comment: Are you sure count_value_wants is not initialized as a string?

Comment: Please also post `getView` method code of `AddToListAdapter` class because as in log you are trying to cast String Value to Integer

Comment: @alexBrand, I am declaring it at class level as global variable and i am not initializing it. Anyways,it would be set as 0 as default.

Answer (score 0):

From the Shared Preferences documentation, on `getInt`:

> Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws
>   ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not
>   an int.

You must be initializing the property `count_key_wants` with a String somewhere.

Comment: No I am not doing that. count_key_wants is just a key value and I am not declaring it as anything.

Comment: Maybe you have a corrupted SharedPreferences file? Try deleting the app from the emulator/phone you're using to test and re-install.

Comment: It worked, strange though... Any logical explanation ?

Comment: It happened to me once while developing.. not sure what could cause it.